# SQL Conditional on Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Why** does this..

```
DECLARE @SkyBlue Bit
SET @SkyBlue = 1
IF @SkyBlue
    Select 'the sky is blue!'
ELSE
    Select 'the sky is not blue!'
```

Produce this

> "An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Select'."

And is there a Boolean type in SQL2008?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@SkyBlue is a bit, not a boolean. Try:

```
DECLARE @SkyBlue Bit
SET @SkyBlue = 1
IF @SkyBlue = 1
    Select 'the sky is blue!'
ELSE
    Select 'the sky is not blue!'
```

Note that this also fails

```
if 1
    Select 'the sky is blue!'
ELSE
    Select 'the sky is not blue!'
```